# C# How to get all URLS relate to a domain scan using Virustotal APIs?

Tags: c#, api, url, get

I am trying to get a list of all Virustotal's scanned URLs related to a list of domains written inside a txt file in my PC.

I tried downloading the whole page source code using HTML Agility Pack with this string to generate the link i need to download via webclient:

> ("https://www.virustotal.com/#/domain/" + domain)

No success because the only thing I got was a stack of 3kb html files.

Now while searching trough the web I found virustotal C# apis, the real problem is that I'm not figuring out how does they work.

Here I'm copying a piece of what i've done till now:

```
//link da scannerizzare con virustotal
string[] LinksScan = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Condivisione\cert-pa download\File 1\AutoLinksDownload1.txt");
//links Provenienti dallo scan
string[] LinksDL = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Condivisione\cert-pa download\File 1\links.txt");

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    int i = 0;
    //Per ogni dominio scrivere gli url derivati in AutoLinksDownload1
    foreach (string line in LinksScan)
    {
        string result;

        if (line.Contains("https://"))//IF LINE CONTAINS "Https://"
        {
            //FILTER (DOMAIN)
            int pFrom1 = line.IndexOf("https://") + "https://".Length;
            int pTo1 = line.LastIndexOf("/");
            //FILTERED STRING
            result = line.Substring(pFrom1, pTo1 - pFrom1);
            Console.WriteLine(result);// Stringa da usare gia filtrata!!!
            //FINE FILTRO
        }
        else//IF Line CONTAINS "Http://"
        {
            //FILTER (DOMAIN)
            int pFrom = line.IndexOf("http://") + "http://".Length;
            int pTo = line.LastIndexOf("/");
            //FILTERED STRING
            result = line.Substring(pFrom, pTo - pFrom);// Stringa da usare gia filtrata!!!
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            //END FILTER
        }
        i++;
        //API VIRUSTOTAL
        VirusTotal virusTotal = new VirusTotal("MY API KEY");
        //USE https
        virusTotal.UseTLS = true;
        //DOMAIN SCAN
        ---> CODE I NEED TO FIGURE OUT
        // GET SCAN RESULT AS STRING
        ---> CODE I NEED TO FIGURE OUT
        //Save urls list on file 
       // File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Condivisione\cert-pa download\File 1\Pagine salvate\" + "pagina" + i + ".html", RESULTVAR);

        ////////////////////////DA CONTINUARE AD IMPLEMENTARE L'API DI VIRUSTOTAL HO 4 RICHIESTE PER MINUTO
    }
    //Aspetto una key
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What exactly in your code does not work yet?

Comment: i'm asking the code to scan domains and how to get the resulting urls list in a txt file.
 //DOMAIN SCAN
        ---> CODE I NEED TO FIGURE OUT
        // GET SCAN RESULT AS STRING
        ---> CODE I NEED TO FIGURE OUT
        //Save urls list on file